# Expanding multiple dates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So i have a list of start days and end days and I want to expand all of them in a different sheet For example:

A1 has a start date and B1 has an end date
A2 has a start date and B2 has an end date
And so on

I want to expand all of those dates in sheet 2 with:

The dates falling between A1 and B1 to fall under the row A
The dates falling between A2 and B2 to fall under the row B

Ad so on!
Can someone help me?

Comment: It's not really clear what your desired outcome is. Could you perhaps include a sample of your input data and a manually created desired output (please include it as text, not a screenshot).
I've proposed an edit which includes the example input data (based on your description). Please edit your question further to include the desired outcome in a similar, tabular format.

Answer (score 2):

With your dates in A1:B2 on a sheet called `Dates`

[image]

Put this formula in the upper left cell in the range into which you want the data.

```
=IF(INDEX(Dates!$A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))+(ROW(1:1)-1)>INDEX(Dates!$B:$B,COLUMN(A:A)),"",INDEX(Dates!$A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))+(ROW(1:1)-1))
```

Then copy over and down

[image]

`INDEX(Dates!$A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))` and `INDEX(Dates!$B:$B,COLUMN(A:A))` return the start date and end date respectively.  As the formula is dragged across it goes down one row.

Then we simply add `1` to the date as it is dragged down till it equals the end date and then return blank strings.

Comment: +1 for deciphering the cryptic question

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Not positive I did, but it is what makes sense to me.  I may be totally wrong.